# Multiplicative quotient - what's the correct notation? Does a quotient group contain singletons or cosets?

Tags: group-theory, notation, quotient-group

I want to learn the correct notation and language with which to communicate clearly about a quotient on the multiplicative group $G=(\Bbb Q^+,\times)$

In particular, I want to know the notation with which to clearly identify the cosets and the unique indexing elements.

The equivalence relation is $x\sim y\iff\exists i,j\in\Bbb Z:2^i \times3^j\times x=y$

Let $N$ be the 3-smooth numbers then $1\sim n\iff n\in N$ so I think this is a normal subgroup of $G$ and the equivalence class of the identity element.

Then the multiplicative group generated by the primes greater than $3$ is its dual and the quotient group.  So I think I would write $G/N=Q$

Then every element of $G$ has a unique representation as $q\times n:q\in Q, n\in N$

All good so far, what I'm not clear on now is how to express (in notation) the unique representatives and their cosets.

---

Tentatively I think I can write $q\in Q$ and $[q]=q\times N$.

> Is $Q\subset G$ or are $[q]\in Q$?  i.e. does $Q$ contain singletons or cosets?
>
> Assuming $Q$ contains cosets, how do I identify a (the) set of unique indexing elements, and its elements?

I have in mind the unique set satisfying $\lvert x\rvert_2=1=\lvert x\rvert_3$

Comment: How is $G$ even a group to begin with?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft you were of course totally right, v. silly of me. Fixed now.

Comment: You should better denote the positive rationals by $\;\Bbb Q^+\;,\;\;\Bbb Q_+\;$ or something like this. Trying to use less cumbersome notation can make things simpler to understand.

Comment: @DonAntonio ok I've done that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is never true *formally* that $\;Q=G/N\subset G\;$ . The elements of each set are just different.

Next, if you already chose $\;q\in Q=G/N\;$ , then there is no need to use $\;[q]\;$ , which is a notation usually reserved, in this context, to denote equivalence classes for an element in the *original* set. Thus, if you take $\;g\in G\;$ , then it'd make sense to talk about $\;[g]:=gN\in G/N=Q\;$ (no need of multiplication sign $\;g\times N\;$ , which could be confusing) .

The elements of $\;Q=G/N\;$ are cosets, which is the name given in this context to the *equivalence classes* in $\;G\;$ we get fro the equivalence relation determined by $\;N\lhd G\;$ .

Thus, a singleton in $\;Q\;$ could be denoted by $\;\left\{\;[g]\;\right\}=\left\{\;gN\;\right\}\;$ , for any $\;g\in G\;$ .

I think you're having some trouble understanding all this, and you chose a rather problematic example of subgroup in a rather problematic group (for a beginner). There are way simpler examples of groups and normal subgroups to work your way through these definitions.

Comment: Thank-you. Which are you saying is not *formally* true: $Q=G/N$ or $G/N\subset G$? I think the 2nd because $G/N$ is more like $\subset\mathcal P(G)$? There is one further part I should have asked which is naturally part of the same question... Every $gN$ contains a unique indexing element $x$ which satisfies $\lvert x\rvert_2=\lvert x\lvert_3=1$.  What would be a natural way to talk of this set of unique indexing elements? I don't find this group hard at all because it's just $\Bbb Z^{<\omega}$. I understand it but I need to communicate what I understand to others!

Comment: (and the quotient is $Q=\Bbb Z^{<\omega}/\Bbb Z^2$)... actually my apologies, the question *did* ask for the "unique indexing element", but I failed to identify what I meant by that.

Comment: @RobertFrost By **your** definition, $\;Q=G/N\;$ . Nobody can say this isn't true: it is just a definition. What isn't true is $\;G/N\subset G\;$ *formally* . And no, again: $\;G/N\;$ CANNOT be an element of the power set $\;\mathcal P(G)\;$ of G, since its elements are **not** elements of $\;G\;$ .... Next, I really don't understand what you mean by "indexing element", and even less what $\;|x|_2\;,\;\;|x|_3\;$ can possibly mean within this context. With all due respect, I think you have big problems understanding these rather basic things of elementary group theory.

Comment: Sorry, $N$ is the multiplicative group generated by the primes $2,3$ so there's a map $\forall n\in N: h:n\mapsto 1$.  Then its true for every coset $gN$ that $h$ can identify the unique element of $gN$ which has the primes $2,3$ factored out. Doing so identifies a unique indexing element for every coset which satisfies $\lvert x\rvert_2=\lvert x\lvert_3=1$.  This is just like in an additive cyclic group modulo $n$ where we would identify some number $p$ such that $0\leq p<n$ as the unique identifying element of its coset. I don't know how I identify that unique indexing element.

Comment: The elements of $G$ aren't elements of the powerset of $G$.  The subsets of $G$ are elements of the powerset of $G$, which would make the cosets, being subsets of $G$, elements of the powerset of $G$, surely?

Comment: @RobertFrost I think what you call "indexing element" of a coset is really a [representative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Notation_and_formal_definition) of the equivalence class. In general, there is no canonical choice of such representatives, so there is no notation for that.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudD. Just what I needed to know. I find it surprising there is not a representative because of course in addition modulo $n$ we identify the unique representative $p$ in the range $0\leq p< n$, often without even thinking of the coset.

Comment: @RobertFrost You missed the "in general" part. That can still happen in some particular cases such as the one you mention.

Comment: @ArnaudD. p.s. I'm right about $Q\subset\mathcal P(G)$, right?

Comment: @RobertFrost Yes, you are. I guess DonAntonio misread your comment as $Q\in \mathcal{P}(G)$, which, as he said, is false.

Comment: @ArnaudD. ah yes, I did't spot that. Thanks.

Comment: @ArnaudD. In fact I also read $\;Q\subset \mathcal P(G)\;$ ...and the set of elements **in the group** $\;Q=G/N\;$ cannot be considered as a set of subsets of $\;G\;$ , imo. Now, if we take each coset as a set ,then yes...I guess this depends on what point of view one is taking. So **the set** of cosets of a subgroup in a group is a set of subsets of $\;G\;$ ...

Comment: ok thanks @DonAntonio that's one thing I was trying to determine; whether you were just making a fine distinction or whether I had fundamentally misunderstood something.